# Mi código no encuentra el archivo especificado

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una galería light box, al principio cada imagen tiene un efecto (hover) donde sale un fondo negro que lo cubre un 60%, mi problema es que cuando pongo la ventana modal al dar clic en una imagen esta no se manifiesta en su ventana correspondida

Me sale el error `undefined:1 GET file:///C:/wamp/www/proyectos/Paginas/plantillas/Galeria/modelo%202/undefined net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Pero tanto las variables de "fotoModal" como "imagenes" las probé con un "alert()".

Este es mi codigo javascript:

```js
const descriptor = document.querySelectorAll(".container-description");
const imagenes = document.querySelectorAll(".litlle, .large, .big");
let contador = true,
  lightBoxModal = document.querySelector(".modal-light- galery"),
  contadorVentana = true,
  botonCancelar = document.querySelector(
    ".descriptor-modal .cancelar-modal-one img"
  ),
  fotoModal = document.querySelector(".photo-modal img");

function hoverImages() {
  for (let i = 0; i < imagenes.length; i++) {
    //Efecto hover de imagenes
    imagenes[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
      if (contador == true) {
        descriptor[i].style.height = "60%";
        contador = false;
      }
    });
    imagenes[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
      if (contador == false) {
        descriptor[i].style.height = "0%";
        contador = true;
      }
    });

    //Efecto hover de imagenes

    //Light-box
    imagenes[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (contadorVentana == true) {
        lightBoxModal.style.display = "grid";
        fotoModal.src = imagenes[i].src;
        contadorVentana = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
hoverImages();

botonCancelar.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (contadorVentana == false) {
    lightBoxModal.style.display = "none";
    contadorVentana = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: el error que se sale es que no encuentra la foto, lo mas probable es que estas concatenando la variable incorrecta o no estas leyendo bien los datos para mostrar la imagen.

Comment: Como dice @tecnobyte, el problema no pasa por las funciones flecha (por lo que deberías cambiar el título de tu pregunta), sino que es porque no encuentra el archivo especificado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, pero probé ambos con un "alert()" y ambos funcionaron, las variables que quiero enlazar las variables "imagenes" y " fotoModal"

Comment: revisa la url, hay un undefined, por lo que, o no se registro correctamente o JavaScript no reconoce el ultimo carácter que no creo que sea, pero revisa si están bien los datos en `fotoModal.src = imagenes[i].src;`

Comment: Pienso que si es ese código, he estado igualando "fotoModal.src" con el nombre especifico de las imágenes respectivas y si cumple su función

Comment: @maranwind que lo hayas probado con un alert no asegura que la ruta este en lo correcto, el alert simplemente te mostrara la url que contiene cada objeto de tu arreglo. Lo que tienes que asegurarte es que esa ruta este referenciando correctamente al archivo físico. Podrías por ejemplo tomar el src de una imagen y pegarla en una pestaña de tu navegador, algo como `https://localhost/ruta/hacia/imagen.jpg` y asegurarte que te muestra la imagen correctamente :D

Comment: En tal caso, ¿puedes darme alguna recomendación para llegar a una solución?

Comment: muestra los datos de `imagenes[i].src` al recorrer el ciclo

Comment: @maranwind podrías empezar por lo que te recomende más arriba; tomar un src, pegarlo en otra pestaña de tu navegador y mirar que es lo que te trae. Podrías incluir también en la pregunta un ejemplo del src que estas obteniendo al hacer click, así tenemos más visualización de lo que esta pasando

Comment: Acabo de recorrer el ciclo y pude darme cuenta de cual era la solución, en la constante "const imagenes = document.querySelectorAll(".litlle, .large, .big");" estaba haciendo un recorrido por los contenedores, mas no por la imagenes en sí, muchas gracias